# Are the creatures in the ship aliens or future humans?

Tags: knowing

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowing_%28film%29), the inhabitants of the ship at the end of [Knowing](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0448011/) are aliens.  But don't I remember that they are actually the descendants of humans from the distant future, come to Earth to rescue their own ancestors?

Comment: Where did you read that they were descendants of humans from the distant future ?

Comment: I thought that was implied or stated in the movie.  Possibly I imagined or assumed that...

Comment: IIRC It's not mentioned anywhere in the movie. They have just glossed over that part. Though it's a good hypothesis. But I feel they are aliens. Sort of like the sanctuary keepers of the earth.

Comment: In light of the direct quote from the script, I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive. Was there anything holding you back from considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 2):

### The [shooting script](http://www.screenplaydb.com/film/scripts/knowing_screenplay.PDF) makes it pretty clear that they're aliens.

> *Its form is so unearthly that it could only be one thing. Ted sinks to his knees in shock before the logic-defying sight of... **AN ALIEN
>   SPACECRAFT.***

and

> *Ted stares in absolute awe...Then he hears that WHITE NOISE again in
>   his head... **and the alien is gone**. The ramp withdraws into the ship,
>   and the portal irises closed to make the spacecraft seamless again.*

Answer (score -1):

These are the "angels" from ancient biblical lore. You can see their wings. The movie plainly implies they were sent to save the children of mankind from the destruction of earth. At the end of the film the children are dropped off at new habitable planets to re-seed our species. And the "Tree of Life" is what they are running towards in the background. It is a wonderful and hopeful message that we are not alone. That those who created us want us to survive.

Comment: The script clearly states that they're aliens.